# Java Swing: Why can't I drawImage() on an instance of JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, components, instance, paint

Without going into grave detail, I'm working toward creating a desktop-like program in Swing, with icons drawn on top of a background image. Usually I subclass JPanel or another JComponent and draw on that, but wanted to try something new just for kicks, and tried drawing on an *instance* of JFrame, without making my program a subclass of it.

I am aware that this is not the accepted way of doing this, but discovering that the image was not drawn has exposed a missing link (one of the many, I suppose) in my understanding of Swing and how it paints components.

What confuses me is that if my program subclasses JFrame and I override the paint() method (the accepted way, in other words), it will draw the image into the JFrame, but it will not do this for an instance of JFrame in my non-subclassed program.

Hopefully the code showing essentially what I want to do will help:

```
public class ImageLoader
{
    BufferedImage img = null;
    JFrame window = null;

public ImageLoader()
{
    try
    {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/strawberry.jpg"));
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    window = new JFrame("Strawberry Viewer");

    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);

    //Why can't I do something akin to the following to draw on an instance of JFrame?
    Graphics g = window.getGraphics();
    paint(g);
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new ImageLoader();
}

}
```

I have read Oracle's page ["Painting in AWT and Swing"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html/) but I'm still not understanding why I can't draw on an instance of JFrame. Is there any situation where I could draw on an instance of a component, or do they all have to be subclassed if I want to draw on them?

Finally, if the problem is based largely on my gross misunderstanding of how Swing works, what are some recommended books or other resources for understanding Swing?

Thanks for the help in advance. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use getGraphics() to do painting.

Anything you do with that Graphics object will only be temporary. Then next time Swing determines the frame needs to be repainted you will lose the painting.

In your case you use pack() so the frame is minimized. When you resize the frame, the normal frame painting will paint over your image. So try using `setSize(500, 500);`.

However even this won't work because your image will be painting before the normal painting has completed. Not all code is executed sequentially.

Try the following to delay the painting of the image:

```
try
{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    Graphics g = window.getGraphics();
    paint(g);
}
catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

When the image shows, then try resizing the frame and you will lose the image.

> if my program subclasses JFrame and I override the paint() method

Don't override paint() of a JFrame (yes, it will work, but it is NOT the way painting was designed to be done in Swing). Custom painting is done by overriding paintComponent() of a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame.

> if the problem is based largely on my gross misunderstanding of how Swing works

The Swing tutorial is the best place to start for Swing basics. See the section on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to get your started.

For a more technical article see [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

Comment: Thanks camickr. That helps, I think. The trick delaying the thread was actually pretty revealing as to what seems to be happening behind the scenes. Anyway, I've checked out all of those resources you mentioned in the past, but I'll run through them again to see what I might have missed.